# executing dynamic shell script command that uses mixed quotes and asterix

Tags: bash, shell, quotes

I have the following which I'm trying to script.  I've hit a wall with trying to cater for the mixed quotes as well as asterix.

This is what I have

```
cmd_1="/usr/local/nz/bin/nzsql -d ${SOURCE_DB} -c "
cmd_2="\"create external table '${EXTERNAL_PATH}${EXTERNAL_FILE}'"
cmd_3=" USING (QUOTEDVALUE 'DOUBLE' ESCAPECHAR '\' DELIM ',' TIMESTYLE '24HOUR' LOGDIR '${EXTERNAL_PATH}' ENCODING 'INTERNAL')"
cmd_4=" as select * from ${SOURCE_TABLE}\""
cmd=${cmd_1}${cmd_2}${cmd_3}${cmd_4}
```

Which when echo'd looks fine and in fact runs with a copy and paste to the command line.

```
/usr/local/nz/bin/nzsql -d mydatDba -c "create external table '/datawarehouse/development/externaldata/output/EXT_mytable.csv' USING (QUOTEDVALUE 'DOUBLE' ESCAPECHAR '\' DELIM ',' TIMESTYLE '24HOUR' LOGDIR '/datawarehouse/development/externaldata/output/' ENCODING 'INTERNAL') as select * from mytable"
```

To get it to echo correctly, I did have to wrap ${cmd} in double quotes and so did the same for the execute which looks like this.

```
"${cmd}"
```

When running from the shell script however I receive : No such file or directory.  I have verified the directories involved and as I mentioned can actually copy and paste what's generated to the command line and it works fine.

I can only assume that what is being echoed in both my echo command and the error is not actually what's being executed.

Advise on how to get the 'real' command echoed and or on my use of quotes would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: If you enclose the command in quotes it will be treated as a single element rather than a list of separate ones.  So the whole string will be treated as the command name, rather than a command followed by options, which is why it cannot be found.

Comment: Why are you putting the command in a variable? Depending on your goal, there are generally better alternatives: just execute it directly, use a function, or use an array. (Note that `eval` is not in that list, because it's usually a bad idea.) See [BashFAQ #050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the built-in `eval` command:

```
eval "$cmd"
```

Comment: Thanks heaps;  I was looking at this last night but skipped over trying it.  much appreciated & thanks again